# Show that $\binom {2n}n \leq(2n)^{\pi (2n)}$ where $\pi(2n) $ is number of prime number less than $2n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

> Show that  $$\binom {2n}n \leq(2n)^{\pi (2n)}$$ 
>   where, as usual,  $\pi(2n) $ is number of prime number less than $2n$.

I was solving basic techniques of combinatorial theory by Daniel Cohen.
I was stuck at ch-2 problem 72. can anyone help me out with this problem:

> Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of primes less than or equal to $x$.
>   (a) Use the previous problem to show that $$ \binom{2n}{n} \le (2n)^{\pi(2n)} $$

The previous problem 71 says this:

[image: Snippet of previous problem]

Comment: Could you also join the statement of the previous problem that is given as a hint?

Comment: Its the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim follows immediately from part c) of the rprevious exercise:
If $r_p$ is the maximal exponent with which $p$ divides ${2n\choose n}$, then
$${2n\choose n}=\prod_{p\le 2n} p^{r_p}\le \prod_{p\le 2n} 2n =(2n)^{\pi(2n)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\nu_p(x)$ the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of the integer $x$ then 
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\prod_{p\leq2n}p^{\nu_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)}\leq\prod_{p\leq2n}p^{\ln_p(2n)}=\prod_{p\leq2n}2n=(2n)^{\pi(2n)}.$$
where we used the inequality 
$$\nu_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\nu_p\left((2n)!\right)-2\nu_p\left(n!\right)=
\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\ln_p(2n)\rfloor}1\leq\ln_p(2n).$$